# Cast TreeViewItem to XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, xsd

I'm trying to iterate through the `XElement` of two collections so I can compare them, but I get the error :

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 
>   'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem' to type
>   'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.'

My code is:

```
private void CompareTrees(ItemCollection xml,ItemCollection xsd )
    {               
        bool isMatch = false;
        string header = string.Empty;           

        foreach (XElement xexsd in xsd)
        {
            foreach (XElement xexml in xml)
            {                    
                    if (xexsd.Name.LocalName + " - " + xexsd.Value == xexml.Name.LocalName + " - " + xexsd.Value)
                    {
                    CompareTrees(xml, xsd);
                    isMatch = true;
                    break;
                    }    
            }
            if (isMatch == true)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                var item = new ListBoxItem();
                lbItems.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint at your 2 foreach loops and you will see that the the collection in either xsd or xml (or both) are actual collections of System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem. As such, you cannot cast them to System.Xml.Linq.XElement as the former does not inherit from the latter.

Comment: thanks, but i get that Content is not part of the TreeViewItem Library

Comment: You're not asking any question here.

Comment: Change from : CompareTrees(xml, xsd); to : CompareTrees(xexml, xexsd);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `ItemCollection` contains `TreeViewItems`. Try this:

```
foreach (TreeViewItem tvi in xml.OfType<TreeViewItem>())
{
    XElement xexsd = tvi.DataContext as XElement;
    if (xexsd != null && xexsd.Name.LocalName + " - " + xexsd.Value == xexml.Name.LocalName + " - " + xexsd.Value)
    {
        CompareTrees(xml, xsd);
        isMatch = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should replace your foreach (XElement xexml in xml) or the other loop or both. Impossible to say based on the (lack of) information you have provided. Like I said, the error message means that the ItemCollection contains TreeViewItems.

Comment: Did you try this or what happened?

Comment: So you did get rid of the compilation error which was your original issue? If you have a new issue you should ask a new question.

Comment: yes, it finally works when i remplaced each foreach with your code ! thanks